# How can I fix a floor joist that has separated from the cross beam?

Tags: floor, joists, support

I have just 1 beam that is no longer in the notch that is supposed to rest in on the crossbeam. The house is 100 years old. Would it be a safe option to install a floor jack to bring the beam back up to where it had been? The floor is bouncy due to this. The joist is in an area where there is a lot of foot traffic.

Comment: Personally, I'd ask an engineer before doing anything to that. What are you going to do if lifting the beam makes the other end slip free? What are you going to do to prevent it from slipping out again? The best answer may not be the obvious answer, and I'm not sure there is an obvious answer.

Comment: I agree with @keshlam, it's not obvious to me what to do about this. It's possible the building has settled in such a way that by jacking the beam back up you'll put pressure on other parts of the structure. Sistering the beam may be the way to go. I would get a professional to look at it, preferably someone with experience in old houses (which may be common or rare, depending on your area).

Comment: You could jack it up enough just to hold it in place. I wouldn't do anything else with it until you consult a professional.

Comment: I think we need to see some pictures of the beam and the floor above it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in everybody's comments, this is not a place to go blindly.

For the joist to "slip out of" its notch, something else has probably moved. This can lead to a house-sized game of "Jenga®" where the players (being you and anybody else in the house) can be crushed by the falling timbers.

Hire yourself a civil/structural consulting engineer, preferably one that really understands old wooden houses if yours is (as it sounds like it might be) a post and beam (P&B) structure. Those working for new P&B companies might be your best bet, and if they are not, they will usually know someone who does do work with old P&B houses, in most cases.